# how to get blob datatype image stored from the SQLite database and save it to another table?

Tags: image, sqlite, display

please how to get the image stored from the SQLite database and save it to another table?
for example, I have a user table with the user image saved as blob data type, and I want to retrieve that login user image in the resumeActivity and save it to his resume in the resume table.
how to do that?
I've tried many options but non seem working.

what I did was, I passed the user name from the login page and used getIntent method to get the data.
and read from the database. I get the username alright. But the Image not showning..
Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

thanks.

```
   String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("key_name");

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Publish Record");
    actionBar.setSubtitle(userName);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String q = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='" +userName + "'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(q, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            this.name = cursor.getString(1);
            this.image = cursor.getBlob(6);

            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
            Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            postImageTV.setImageBitmap(theImage);


        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the *resume* table and where is it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the data first get the size of the data :

The get the data using :

```
    imageSize = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, position-in-queryresult)
    image = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, position-in-statement)
```

Then create image from image pointer and imageSize.
Writing blob is done through :

```
    sqlite3_bind_blob(statement,  position-in-statement, image, imageSize, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
```

specifying the data to write and its size

Also another comment  about :

```
"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='" +userName + "'"
```

Edit : It is safer to use a statement and bind parameters to prevent sql injections